# Mod error due to input vector in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

```
m<=(s-1) mod 2
```

Here 'm' is a signal while s is an input vector 
While trying to implement the code I am getting an error "mod cannot have such operands in this context"
Error might be due to trying to get mod of vector value.
Is there any way to either equate the vector to an integer value or correct the error via some other method?

Answer (score 3):

Since `mod 2` is basically just extracting the last bit of the vector and the `-1` is just negating this, why not just do:

```
m <= not s(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume 's' is defined as a 'std_logic_vector'.  You better/should use 'unsigned' or 'signed' from the 'ieee.numeric_std' library for those operators.  You can convert your 'std_logic_vector' to 'signed' or 'unsigned' with a typecast.  E.g. unsigned(s).
Anyhow: Sonicwave's solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Either use an `integer` for the vector instead (ie change the type of the signal) or convert it to an `integer` before `mod`ing

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

i := to_integer(unsigned(s));
m := (i-1) mod 2;
```